# How can I prevent oracle to create minidumps?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

For some reason, our application sometimes loses connections with the Databases, and then a LOT of minidumps are generated.

[image]

How can I track the reason for these minidumps? how can I enable something to prevent this to be created?

Reading those files there is only a picture of all windows events running. there's no useful information.

I'm new with oracle and i'm pretty sure there is  some button to disable it.

Across all websites I could see people upgrading clients, service packs and etc. Like this one:

https://superuser.com/questions/438315/process-keeps-creating-dump-files

EIDT: Even after upgrading the software and environment, I have a lot of minidumps.

Comment: The answer by Michael is valid. It's related to Windows because as far as it is concerned a program it was running has crashed. You can disable them but it will hide the issue. Why don't you work on making your network more reliable so you aren't dropping connections?

Comment: I guess I should add you could also add exception handling in your program so it handles the network issues gracefully rather than crash.

Oracle can create dump files when issues occur, but these are not from Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

## Minidump files

The "minidump files" appear to be a Windows OS thing.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307973/how-to-configure-system-failure-and-recovery-options-in-windows

But, if you disable them, you will just be hiding the fact that there is a problem.

I would prefer to hunt down the reason why they are being created and fix that problem.

The first thing to do is check which version you are running. For example, version 11.2.0.1 is known to be buggy.  If that is the case, your first step should be upgrading your database.

After that, I would look at the Oracle Alert logs and go from there.

**note:**  ORA-600/7554 usually means "Call Oracle Support".